# UV Map faces do not match face in edit mode

Tags: texturing, uv, vector-mapping

My faces don't match the UV map faces selected, I've been trying to figure it out the whole day. The UV map is correct and is correctly correlating to the faces, but the texture placement is completely wrong on the model..

What do I do?

[image]

Comment: May be you have multiple UVMaps or the shader not UV based.

Comment: How do I make sure I only have one UV map? Also how do I check that the shader is UV based?

Comment: Ah!! Worked! I did have multiple UV maps. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I'm glad. If you use this node in your material (not the UV socket) then it will not UV based. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html Otherwise the Blender will use the UVMap for coordinates.